# java.lang.IllegalStateException: getWriter() has already been called for this response, Even thought its called only once

Tags: spring-boot, csv, servlet-3.0, opencsv

I am using `spring-boot`. I want to send a CSV as the attachment of response for which I am using `opencsv` to write bean to response. Even though `response.getWriter()` is called only once, I am getting this exception.

While searching for solution, I came to know that we cannot use `response.getWriter()` and `response.getOutputStream()` together. But this is not the case here.

I am only calling getWriter and exactly once.

I also checked if it was due to `opencsv` library by writing a plain string to it e.g. "name, test". But still the same error. So it's not due to `opencsv` either.

```
private Pair<Boolean, String> writeCSVToResponse(List<QuestionDownloadResponse> qdrList,  HttpServletResponse response) {
    String fileName = new SimpleDateFormat("'CSV'yyyyMMddHHmmss'.csv'").format(new Date());
    response.reset();
    response.setContentType("application/csv");
    response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION,
            "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    //Find answer, for now we will return any if exists
    try {
        Writer writer = response.getWriter();
        // Create Mapping Strategy to arrange the  
        // column name in order 
        final CustomCSVMappingStrategy<QuestionDownloadResponse> mappingStrategy = new CustomCSVMappingStrategy<>();

        mappingStrategy.setType(QuestionDownloadResponse.class); 

        StatefulBeanToCsv<QuestionDownloadResponse> sbc = new StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder<QuestionDownloadResponse>(writer)
           .withSeparator(CSVWriter.DEFAULT_SEPARATOR)
           .withMappingStrategy(mappingStrategy)
           .build();

        sbc.write(qdrList);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        CMSQuestionServiceImpl.logger.error("Error in CSV IO operations", e);
        return Pair.of(false, "Failed to Open file");
    } catch (CsvDataTypeMismatchException | CsvRequiredFieldEmptyException e) {
        CMSQuestionServiceImpl.logger.error("Error in CSV Write operation", e);
        return Pair.of(false,"Failed to write in csv");
    }
```

}

Why is this exception coming, even when response.getWriter is called exactly once. How to solve this issue.

Comment: Can you provide the method signature?

Comment: edited with method signature. Note:: This method is not inside controller, it is inside service file.

Comment: This is the method signature inside the controller :: `@GetMapping(value = "/downloadCSV")
 public String downloadCSV(@RequestBody(required = false) List<Integer> items, HttpServletResponse response){ `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. The problem was that I was sending a String (a message) in response in the controller, but in service, I am sending an attachment. So getWriter() was being called first time in service by me, and the second time by spring to write the response message of type String. Solution: I set the return type of method in the controller to `void` ex::

`@GetMapping(value = "/downloadCSV") 
public void downloadCSV(@RequestBody(required = false) List<Integer> items, HttpServletResponse response){`

The only problem is if something goes wrong in service, you cannot send an error message and there are other alternatives to overcome it.

Answer (score 2):

**I had the same error:** in `spring-boot`

This error occures when we use a `RestExceptionHandler` which tries to modify the response by using `response.getOutputStream()`, remember, the `response.getWriter()` is already called (even once in our code).

So when we call `response.getWriter()` , and we have some exception, the `RestExceptionHandler` executes the `response.getOutputStream()` which causes `java.lang.IllegalStateException: getWriter() has already been called for this response.`

What I suggest to do is to add `try-catch` to the `response.getWriter()` and when you catch any exception we have to reset the response by using `response.reset()` like that:

```
try {
      writer.write(beans);
    } catch (Exception e) {
            response.reset();
            throw e;
    }
```

After throwing the exception, the `RestExceptionHandler` will do its job.